# Calculating throughput

Tags: jmeter

I am creating a tool like J meter for load testing . I have created say 20 threads and I executed all of them in say 4 iteration .

My code is such a way that first all threads from iteration 1 will get completed then second set of threads will start.

Each thread is doing something like login etc etc . I need to calculate the throughput ? Can someone please guide me what is the correct way . Currently i am following the below procedure.

I captured the start time when in first iteration i was about to create threads
System.currentTimeMillis();

and end time i have taken as Last thread from last iteration was calculated? Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to get first iteration time, JMeter provides `TESTSTART.MS` variable which holds timestamp in milliseconds since 1st Jan 1970 indicating when your test started, see [Pre-defined Properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedprops) chapter of JMeter User Manual
2. You don't need to calculate throughput yourself, JMeter provides [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener which automatically calculates throughput from test results

   [image: Aggregate Report Throughput]

   If you need the formula for some reason, according to [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) it is:

   > **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
   >
   > The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).
3. And finally you can even set the target throughput via [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to calculate the time difference before and after the operation that you are doing in each thread instead of doing it before and after iteration to get more accurate results.

Thread handling has its own latency which can affect your final throughput. Also calculate throughput for each thread separately and add them to get the final throughput.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Basically  Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).

Assume to generate load, you need to do 10 number of requests in 2 threads so 5 requests per thread (in case of uniform distribution ). In this case you can calculate throughput in two ways.

***First: (approach that you have used)***

a. Get time before starting threads.

b. Get time after all 2 threads complete.
Then

> final_tput  = 10 / (Total time taken by 2 threads)

***Second:***

a. In thread1 gather time delta for each request and add them to get the total time (taken by 5 request). Then calculate TPUT for the thread by

> thread1_tput = 5 / (Total time taken by 5 requests)

b. Do same calculation for thread2 and calculate TPUT for second thread.

> thread2_tput = 5 / (Total time taken by 5 requests)

After that final TPUT will be

> final_tput = thread1_tput + thread2_tput

Second approach is more accurate as it does not include time taken by thread handling.

Comment: What do you mean by calculating the throughput for each thread?Can you please explain a bit

Answer (score -1):

Aggregate Report will provide you solution. Just add this under Listener's in Thread group. Here you can see the clear throughput value changes.